# Who does Chewbacca meet at the end of his comic series?

Tags: star-wars, marvel, character-identification, chewbacca

### Spoilers for the 2015 *Chewbacca* series below.

At the end of the *Chewbacca* comic series, Chewie returns to Kashyyyk and reunites with some Wookiees.

[image: Chewbacca's family]

[image: Chewbacca's family]

Do we know the names of these Wookiees, or their relation to Chewbacca?

Is there any evidence that they're the same as [Chewie's old family](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Attichitcuk's_family) from Legends?

Comment: In latest novel: Star Wars: Life Debt, it is stated that Chewbacca has a family of his own on Kashykk, however, I do not believe we are given their names

Comment: Itchy, Lumpy, and Mala?

Answer (score 1):

In the new canon, the names of Chewbacca's family from the Holiday Special are listed as his old family, so I don't see a reason why it couldn't be them.

Comment: Good answer, but can you provide a source for that assertion?